# iOS framework with dynamic import third party framework or lib

Tags: objective-c

I need to use a third party lib or framework in my framework with Objective C, and I need to dynamically import this third party framework. My situation is like below:

My framework is used for advertising, and someone like to use "A Advertisers" and "B Advertisers", so he just only need these two AD Framework, but the other one needs "A Advertisers" and "C Advertisers", so he needs these two AD Framework.

I've got no idea to find an answer with Google. I'm needing your hands, thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a framework dynamically with `NSBundle`. All you need is the path to the directory of the bundle:

```
NSString *bundlePath = ...;
NSBundle *framework = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];

// loading the code
[framework load];
// retrieving a specific class
Class aClass = [framework classNamed:@"NameOfSpecificClass"];
```

See [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/LoadingBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001273-100329) for details.

Since iOS doesn't officially supports custom dynamic libs in app bundles, you shouldn't use them. Even if you can load it with `dlopen` and `dlsym` you have to codesign them for deployment.